# Proper GCC setting for my CPU

Tags: linux, gcc, arm

I'm trying to compile a simple C program for my Colibri T20 running Angstrom Linux. The output of uname -a is here:

```
 Linux colibri-t20 3.1.10 #1 SMP PREEMPT Fri Mar 20 02:38:59 CET 2015 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

From that output, my guess is that my -march setting should be armv7l, but looking at this [documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/ARM-Options.html), there is no armv7l.

When I try to compile my program with armv7 setting the compiler outputs this error:

```
error: target CPU does not support ARM mode
```

However, everything works fine when I try to compile it with armv5.
I am using arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc on Ubuntu server. So which options should I use, or should I find a different compiler?